# Breaking changes to eieio in Emacs 27?

Tags: eieio, emacs27

**Q:** are there breaking changes to `eieio` in Emacs 27?

I just upgraded to the Emacs 27 snapshot, and I'm getting a
peculiar break in code that works in previous versions of Emacs.

#### walkthrough

Here's a toy class and a toy `:after` method:

```
(defclass simple-class ()
  ((value
    :initarg :value
    :initform nil
    :documentation "Test slot"))
  "Test class.")
```

This works:

```
(simple-class :value "some value") ;; ==> #s(simple-class "some value")
```

Now I'd like to define an `:after` method on `initialize-instance`:

```
(cl-defmethod initialize-instance :after ((sc simple-class) &key)
  (with-slots (value) sc
    (setf value (upcase value))))
```

Now it's broken:

```
(simple-class :value "some value") ;; ==> (error "Keyword argument nil not one of nil")
```

NB: it's nothing about the content of the `:after` method: I can
define an empty method and I get the same error.

```
(cl-defmethod initialize-instance :after ((sc simple-class) &key))
```

#### what happened?

So: have there been changes to `eieio` (specifically,
`cl-defmethod`) in Emacs 27 that break previous code?  Or is there
something bizarre about the snapshot?

Comment: Might be incorrect use of `&key` with no following arg name, I think Emacs got stricter about that. By the way, in 25.3, I get `Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument char-or-string-p nil)` after the `cl-defmethod`, did you mean `(simple-class :value "some value")`?

Comment: Fixed the typos; sorry. Not sure how else one would define an after method without &keys here.

Comment: what do you think `&key` means in an expression like `(cl-defun foo (x &key) nil)`?

Comment: We need the `&key` to maintain the same number of arguments.  Removing `&key` throws an error to that effect.

Comment: `C-h n` (`view-emacs-news`) is usually the starting point for *"What's new?"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So: have there been changes to `eieio` (specifically, `cl-defmethod`) in Emacs 27 that break previous code?

It's not a change in `eieio` or `cl-defmethod` directly; what's changed is the handling of the `&key` symbol in `cl-def*` macros.

> ```
> (cl-defmethod initialize-instance :after ((sc simple-class) &key))
> ```

In Emacs 26 and earlier this produces a function which accepts any number of arguments (this is a bug: there is only one argument in the arglist, named `sc`).  In Emacs 27 it produces a function which accepts only one argument (`sc`).  The correct argument list for `initialize-instance` (in all versions of Emacs) would be like this:

```
(cl-defmethod initialize-instance :after ((sc simple-class) &optional slots))
```

As told by `<f1> f initialize-instance RET`:

> ```
> initialize-instance is a compiled Lisp function in ‘eieio.el’.
>
> (initialize-instance THIS &optional SLOTS)
> ```

Comment: Thank you!  NB: the `... &optional slots` version also appears to work with previous versions of Emacs.  Where did you find the information about changes to the `cl-def*` macros?  I didn't see it in the release news.

Comment: @Dan I found it by experiment :) It's not in NEWS because it's a bug fix.